# Is it possible in SSRS to incorporate user input into a report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that looks like the below (ignore how bad it looks it is an early draft)

[image: report 1]

I want the user to be able to run the report for whatever dates they like (using the parameters) and then manually enter the a figure in the total shift mins column and have the report calculate the active shift % (time on calls/total shift mins). Is this possible? And if so can anyone step me through it?

Comment: What you are attempting to do may be better served with Excel and PowerPivot, or something like that. That way, you can pull data, and drop it into a sheet with the calculations you need. SSRS is not going to work outside of exporting the results to Excel, and then doing data entry afterward, including adding needed formulas.

Comment: @R.Richards The issue is I don't want it to be my job to run and process this report, I'd like the end users to be able to do it for themselves but at the same time I don't trust that all of them will understand powerpivot.

Comment: SSRS generally isn't interactive in that fashion, with parameters as the main mechanism to get user input into a report.  You *could* set up a multiple value parameter allowing a user to enter in a series of numbers.  Then you could use RowNumber as an indexer to place those values within a column.  However, that's going to be very awkward and disconnected from which row you're entering information for.

Comment: Definitely possible have built a similar query. Will write it up. I always pass it SQL side in a where clause

Comment: Also your better off looking at agent states for logging on logging off times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally just calculate it off the SQL Query. Much easier and you should be able to achieve the same result/

Because I dont have a good understanding of your tables or the data I am just going to model it off a similar structure to the ones at work.

This would be an example of the query I would use to generate the report.

```
Declare @ReportStart date = '2016/08/01'    -- SSRS will automatically pick up parameter and add it
Declare @ReportEnd   date = '2016/09/01'    -- SSRS will automatically pick up parameter and add it
/*  - - - Exclude the Above in the SSRS Report Query - - - */


Select
    Agent
,   Calls_Handled
,   Calls_Outgoing
,   Total_TalkTime
,   avg.Talk_Time
,   Time_Woked

-- You can get Super Lazy here and just calculate it SQL Side 
--Not too sure as i dont have DBMS to test in but the below should work?
,   Cast(SUM((Cast(Total_TalkTime as FLOAT) / CAST(Time_Woked as FLOAT))*100) as Numeric(4,2)) as [%_Active]
FROM
(
SELECT
    Resource_Name as [Agent]

,   SUM( -- Calculate total Incoming Calls Handled
        Case When [Contact_Type] in ('Incoming') THEN 1
    END) as [Calls_Handled]

,   SUM( -- Calculate total outgoing Calls Made
        Case When [Contact_Type] in ('Outgoing') THEN 1
    END) as [Calls_Outgoing]

,   SUM(Talk_Time) as [Total Talk_Time] -- Calculate Total TalkTim
,   AVG(Talk_Time) as [avg.Talk_Time]   -- Calculate Average TalkTime
From
    dbo.tbl_Cisco_Calls
WHERE
    Even_Time between @ReportStart and @reportEnd
GROUP BY
    Agent
) as call
JOIN
(
    Select
        Agent
    ,   DateDiff(minute,Login_Time, Logout_Time) as [Time_Woked]
    FROM
        tbl_Cisco_Event
    WHERE
        Event_Time between @reportStart and @reportEnd
    Group By
        Agent
) as event
on call.Agent = event.Agent
```

Once you have loaded in the report into SSRS it should Automatically pick up the Parameters @ReportStart and @ReportEnd. I would just then adjust their type to be date so they can be used as a calendar. Then you are all done mate.

**You can also do calculations in SSRS**

It will pick up the Entity So i could do

```
[Total_TalkTime]/[Time_Worked]
```

And then Right Click on the cell and I can select the Number type to be a Percentage (exactly the same as Excel Off memory)

*As previously stated though it is going to be ten times easier to do this in the SQL environment*

Comment: This was a very useful answer. Thanks.